# Bring Access Window On Top When Opened From Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, excel-2010, vba

I have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet that brings in data from an Access 2010 database. The user has to login to be able to access the records. When Access opens, the icon in the taskbar flashes, but stays behind whatever else is on the screen. What I want is for Access to become the active window so that there's no chance of the user missing it.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Don't. MS stopped windows from other applications from stealing input focus for a reason. While you can defeat that using the WinAPI, it's fraught with problems doing so, and it generally really annoys users. If you *must* do something, display a message from Excel that tells the user what they're going to need to do first before launching Access.

Comment: Why can't you collect the credentials in Excel and pass these into the launched Access.Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `AppActivate` before, but I don't necessarily know the pros and cons.

```
Sub ActivateAccess()
  On Error Resume Next
  AppActivate "Microsoft Access"
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```